# Is there a good "email this" solution?

Tags: javascript, html, email

I like the functionality of [Share This](http://sharethis.com/), but I only need the "email this" option using my own custom icon. Is there a sensible way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Add This email-only option](http://www.addthis.com/help/custom-buttons#emailonly)**

> You can create an email-only popup form. This will not affect other AddThis buttons on the page.

Looks simple enough to me

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is a mailto link.  This will often open in a desktop client.  However, Firefox lets you [configure it](http://lifehacker.com/392287/set-firefox-3-to-launch-gmail-for-mailto-links) to use a web service, there are extensions (e.g. [ChromeMailer](http://lifehacker.com/5059724/chromemailer-makes-gmail-chromes-default-mail-handler)) to do the same in other browsers.

It's a little more complicated if you want to send the email from your server.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to use JS to populate an **[A element](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html)**:

```
<a href="mailto:example@mail.com?body=Message body here.">
```

Comment: Such an element is called an [‘a element’](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A), not an ‘a anchor’ (sorry, purist).

Comment: @Marcel, from the DTD: `<!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- ` **anchor** `-->`.  Sorry, purist...

Comment: @Marcel - Thanks. I must have been trying to decide between `A element` and `anchor` and that came out.

Comment: @Peter, you're not the only one, nearly everyone calls that "anchor".  Even the earliest HTML manuals I dig up refer to <A> as the "anchor element"...

Comment: @code, yeah, the very document @Marcel linked calls it an "anchor."

Comment: @Matthew: hehe, you're almost right, I read a bit [further in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#idx-anchor-1), which implies that every `a` element *defines* an anchor, if there's at least one of the attributes 'id', 'name' or 'href' (which is the case here). Only when all three are absent, the `a` element doesn't specify an anchor.

Comment: @code, I have to admit that I just wanted to write “anchor element”, but then I decided to look in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="st_email_button" displayText="Email"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        stLight.options({
                publisher:'12345'
        });
</script>
```

see it [here](http://help.sharethis.com/customization/chicklets)