# Can I send email using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, smtp, smtpclient

Is it possible to send emails using just javascript?

Comment: You can make an AJAX call to a script on your server which does it for you... but that's not really "just javascript" :-)

Comment: Can marketing companies send spam using Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending emails with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.** Using a Webservice. You can make an AJAX call to the service. [EmailYak](http://www.emailyak.com/) is one such service (It's in a private beta now).

**EDIT:**
This is still a server side solution, as the actual email is sent from the server. You are just communicating with a server via AJAX and telling it to send the email.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: **[WARNING!] README:**

> It's a third party library that connects to an external server, take care
>   with the information that you are sending.

---

Another solution on JS you can use a library named [**smtpjs**](https://smtpjs.com/)

Add following library your html on header:

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/smtp.js"></script>
```

Use this **without security**:

```
Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
"smtp.yourisp.com",
"username",
"password");
```

Use this **with security**:

```
Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
{token: "63cb3a19-2684-44fa-b76f-debf422d8b00"});
```

Answer (score 5):

It's actually possible and not all that difficult to build an [SMTP client in Javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20160929000450/http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Building-an-SMTP-Client-with-Prototype/).

But that SMTP client will still need to talk to an SMTP server for getting its emails delivered. And SMTP servers open to everyone are very rare nowadays (because they quickly become Spam conduits and then blocked and/or closed).

However, if the person using the client can supply an SMTP server and user credentials for it (just like with any other general purpose email client), then yes, you can send emails using just javascript.

Comment: That's not really an SMTP client in JavaScript, it's a Mail User Agent sending mail over a PHP backend. The OP asked for "just javascript".

Comment: What @AxelBeckert said. Here's the link to the follow-up article that shows the PHP code calling the PHP `mail()` function to send an email, which is triggered by client-side AJAX: https://web.archive.org/web/20130718210439/http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Sending-Email-with-an-SMTP-Client-Built-with-Prototype-and-PHP/

Answer (score 4):

Note that smtpjs uses a service located at http://smtpjs. It's not truly a Javascript SMTP client. This "utility" means you are uploading your email credentials to the server smtpjs.com. **Use with extreme caution**.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to a `mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body` address which tells the browser to fire up the mail client which then makes the mail ready to send - the user just has to hit "submit".

Code:

```
document.location="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&"+
    "subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body";
```

Comment: Actually, [you can do something like that in javascript](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/592325-can-i-send-email-javascript) without the user having to hit submit. But it assumes there is an email client such as Outlook present on the local machine.

Comment: @DOK: Sure? Can't see that anywhere in the page you linked. And it would be a big, fat security hole.

Comment: @thejh I think that code is pretty easy to find there. It's the first answer to the question. Do a search for "onclick" or "mailto:"

Comment: @DOK: The user still has to click "submit" in the mailclient.

Comment: @thejh So basically you are raising arguments against the answer that you are proposing.

Comment: @DOK: Why not? It's not making it completely unusable, but I wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the message "silently" from an SMTP process, then this needs to be done on the server or by using a hosted service.

If you are happy to use the user's native email program, you could use an approach such as that [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript).