# Does Transcrypt support smtplib?

Tags: python, transcrypt

I need smtplib and other libs
is it possible to use Transcrypt for that purpose?

```
import os
import telebot
import smtplib
import textwrap
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
```

`transcrypt -m -b -n .\my-prog.py`

Import error, can't find any of:
./email/mime/application/MIMEApplication.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, for example see [Main differences with CPython](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt#main-differences-with-cpython):

> Web batteries: Seamless access to any existing JavaScript library has
> been favored over inclusion of many Python libraries in the
> distribution. There are some exceptions to this rule, e.g. math,
> cmath, random, itertools, re, time, datetime and turtle, and some more
> may follow, but in general the accent is on libraries that are
> relevant in the browser.

To send email from a browser, you'll probably [call a third party service using ajax as in these stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454294/can-i-send-email-using-javascript).

To do so from the server side, instead of using js compiled from python in node, you would probably prefer to use python directly.