# help to integrate mailhandler to a simple sendmail form sender/subject/text > mymail@somedomain.com

Tags: java, html, css

Need help or pointers on a mailhandler that i could use on my page

Contactform looks like this

http://pastebin.com/0wYNm3wa

Comment: You will need a server-side language for this

Comment: http://www.lilandparkering.no/kontakt.html this is the page, could you spesify for me? thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

You tagged "Java". If really using java on the backend, take a look at [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/)

If not, the [simplest way](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279460) is to set `<form action="mailto:youremail@email.com">`

A little more customizable way can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript).

But you'll always need an [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) server. Be it yours, or the users'.

Comment: <form action="mailto:my@email.com"> works good if i want it to use the users client, but i want to use the online form that i have.

Comment: this will submit the contents of your form.