# Sending a html form via email as a pdf

Tags: html, forms, pdf

I have made an html form. What i want to happen is when the user clicks submit for the page to be emailed as a pdf (like the pdf that comes up if you print the webpage). I've been looking a all sorts of script but nothing seems to do what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Comment: @Manatherin - how did you get .net from this question?

Comment: @Daniel Im not sure i did, the top rated answer on that has a comment saying it is a standalone executable. You can launch it as a process, passing a URL of the HTML document as argument. a few of the other answers e.g. the one from stuart suggest non .NET examples

Answer (score 2):

You will have to have a server-side component that takes the values, creates the PDF, and then e-mails it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be surprised to hear that not all browsers can easily make pdfs out of web pages. Hence, there is no universal JavaScript command that simply taps into a browser's capabilities. That leaves you with options:

1. Generate the pdf on the server (using, say, [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), and send the email right from the server (using good old [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/)).
2. Generate the pdf on the server, have the user download it, and then transfer it all to his email client. (Might just work, see on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript)).
3. Generate the PDF in the browser, cross-platform. [There are some Javascript-only libraries that can generate PDF.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript)
4. Use Safari's PDF capabilities. Safari can make PDFs just in the print dialog. Explain that to your users and call `window.print()`.