# Basic Javascript-only form button

Tags: javascript, forms, button

I need to make a very basic button, that when clicked sends a particular person an email letting them know that that particular page has a broken pdf embed.

In otherwords, the user view a page containing an embeded pdf. If the pdf is broken, they will click a button.
Someone will get an email saying like "page (insert full page url here) has a broken pdf embed". I cannot use PHP because this is to be deployed on a non-php server.

Ok so if I use a mailto tag like this:

```
 <p><a href="javascript:void(window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body'))">click here</a></p>
```

How do I get the full url path into the body of the message?

Comment: javascript can't send emails. One option would be to have "mailto: ..." in the href of your anchor.

Comment: You cannot sent emails with javascript, you need some kind of server-side technology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [send email with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/send-email-with-javascript)

Comment: So if I go the mailto route, how to I configure it so that when they send the message it automatically has the URL in the message?

Comment: @Andrew: See edit on question

Comment: @Chris once you have the full url (you can extract it using JavaScript and capture it in a variable) you can assign it to body(you already have subject and body).

Comment: @andrew how do I do that. I'm not sure how to get the URL into javascript, nor how to add the variable in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to get the URL and pass it to mailto

```
<p><a href="javascript:void(window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body='+window.location.href+''))">click here</a></p>
```

Comment: Quick Question, If I wanted to format the body like such: 
Text
URL
Text

would that be
     <p><a href="javascript:void(window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body='TEXT+window.location.href+TEXT''))">click here</a></p> 

?

Comment: @Chris it would be like this: ...&body='‌+​TEXT+window.location.href+TEXT+''))"...