# Attachment in outlook through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, outlook, sendmail, attachment

Is there any way to add attachment in outlook through javascript?
I am able to send mail using "mailto" , but it does not provide the option for attachment.
I can do this by server side coding, but i want it to be in client side. So, is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider automating Outlook, see [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajnishkaushik/archive/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007.aspx) for more information. Note, it will work only from Internet Explorer.

In general, I'd recommend using another options such as sending email from a web-server where you can make a web API call and upload the file which should be attached. See [How to send mail with attachment using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273466/how-to-send-mail-with-attachment-using-js) for possible options.

Comment: Thank u ... Actually i cant use activex . This is a constraint... any other solution?