# In ioS, it doesn't ask options of mail app

Tags: ios, cordova, email, cordova-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I have installed Cordova email composer plugin using

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git
```

I have wrote code for sending email below code snippet

```
 cordova.plugins.email.open({
    subject:     'Report',
    attachments: [pdfPath]
});
```

When I call above function it only opens default email app doesn't ask for mail app options, this happens only in ios. How can resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "mail app options"?

Comment: its not showing the compose view

Comment: You can manage it without plugIn. You can do it with anchor tag

Comment: How can i do this please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

In .JS file :

```
var aAnchorMail = document.createElement("a");
aAnchorMail.href = "mailto:" + "abc@gmail.com";
aAnchorMail.target = "_top";
```

Or via HTML :

```
<a href="mailto:name@email.com">Link text</a>
```

Comment: i think plugin will automatically raise the email compose options?

Comment: If it can be done by native web tricks, Why we need plugIn for same?

Comment: Installed cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git

Comment: its not working means email compose with attachment not showing

Comment: Remove that plugin & try upper code. I already used same in one of my Project. Good luck !

Comment: upper code is work for android and ios? how can add the attachment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273466/how-to-send-mail-with-attachment-using-js