# How do you send an email within a SharePoint Hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint, client-side, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a SharePoint Hosted App, and trying to send an email with client-side code.  Would I have to use a Workflow or an Event Receiver to do this?  Can't seem to find any information on this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Workflow from Visual Studio to your project.  Drag and drop Email from the toolbox into your Workflow, setup the parameters and you're workflow is now configured to send an email.

From the client side, you need to include `sp.workflowservices.js`.  Then all you need to do is retrieve the workflow instance and start it.

Comment: If all you need to do is send an email then creating a workflow is overkill

Comment: The only other way to do this is using a remote event receiver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function like this to send emails using JavaScript from a SharePoint-hosted app.

```
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
    var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
    var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': from,
                'To': { 'results': [to] },
                //'CC': { 'results': [cc]}, //Maybe you want to include a CC address?
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
           alert("An email was sent.");
        },
        error: function (args) {
           alert("We had a problem and an email was not sent.");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to send the actual email on the client side but you can form the email and send it to a ASP.Net page that will send the email.

See [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/send-email-with-javascript) for examples.

Comment: Sending an email from Javascript is not the same thing.

Comment: What did you mean by client-side?