# Submit form to email, then redirect to new page (without php)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The client has a section of her site that is not navigable through any other pages.  To get to these pages she wants the user to fill out this form.  It's a non-for-profit, so she basically just wants to see how many people are getting to these pages that have a product available for free so she can report on that.  So there is a page with a form.  She wants the user to submit the form and then be re-directed to another page.  Normally I would do this really easily with PHP but unfortunately she hosts the site through some local fools and they don't support PHP

So the question is, how do I get this form to submit to her email, then redirect to a different page (videos.html) from the current page with the form (video-form.html)?

I have this form:

```
        <form id="myForm" action="mailto:mail@mail.net" method="post" name="VideoFormAction">
            <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="46%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="shade1"><font color="red"><b>*</b></font> Email Address</td>
                    <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="Mail" value="" size="30"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="shade2">Name</td>
                    <td valign="top"><input value="" name="Name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                        <font color="red"><b>*</b></font> = required field
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <button class="button">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
```

I have tried some javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.funducate.net/videos.html";  
    }, 1);
};
</script>
```

Which for whatever reason will not work.  I have found multiple suggestions through search to try many different variations of the above, all of which failed.  The last ditch effort was even putting a timeout into it as you see above.  I imagine it doesn't work because the submit button performs the action="" and then doesn't continue.

Are there any other alternatives?  Remember, I can't use PHP (i know it's ridiculous but it's what I got)

Comment: https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782

Comment: @Anubhav - This looks interesting, how would I modify it to send the Name and Email address from the form?

Comment: you have to go through the documentation..

Answer (score 0):

You could read the form values via either jQuery or javascript, save them to variables, construct a message body and email the form contents.

See below for more information:

[How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/send-email-with-javascript)

[More information on Mandrill](https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782)

After sending the email, redirect the page as you have done (correctly) in your code -- but without the setTimeout.