# Receiving notifications

Tags: notifications, parse-platform, alerts

I run a parse app that is basically an appointment system but I was wondering if there is a way that my app/parse can notify me when someone sets an appointment? As of right now I receive no emails or any kind of alert so I have to stay on the parse site, and refresh it every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is write a cloud code pre save function that sends you an email automatically every time an appointment is saved.

```
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave
```

That link should help you get started on writing a cloud code function on save for your objects.

As far as sending an email from Javascript, I believe it is doable, here is an example of part of a response that could help you:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript
```