# How to send an email to someone from a button click on a web page

Tags: javascript, email

I have a photo [frame designer](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame). The user can select different options for their photo frame and they will be reflected in a visual svg-powered graphic. I need the options the user has selected to be saved and then passed on to the manufacturer. The most obvious way to me is to store their choices in javascript variables and then when an order button is pressed these variables are sent to the manufacturer's email. How achievable is this? And how does the email part work? Here is a snippet of code.

```
$(document).ready (function() {
$('#purple').click (function() {
        $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
        var frameColour = "purple";
});
});
```

Comment: DNS MX query to the destination address to get what smtp server you have to contact. Contact it. Send the email.

Comment: Quick Google shows the question already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript. As @Rajesh mentioned this is typically a server side problem but you can open a local mail client to do it.

Comment: oh right. Thanks. Their answer was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email is a server side functionality..You can check out your server side API for this. Ex: Java mail API
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html