# Html elements not converting in outlook body

Tags: java, javascript, outlook

I wrote java script code to open mail client at the same time i am pre populating to,cc,subject and body.But here problem is as part of body i need some html styles.I write like as follows

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="sendemail" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("#sendemail").click(function() {
        alert("Hai");
        try {

            var email='prospectpartner@gmail.com';
            window.location="mailto:"+email+"?subject=Subject&**body**="+<html>Please attach your invitation letter to this email<b><i>Primary Contact</i></b><br/>First name:</html>;
         }
        catch(err){
            alert(err);
        }
        });
</script>
</html>
```

if you observe the body element value i am giving html elements as part of body.Please see the attached image which is  body of outlook.Those html elements are not converting.Please see the below image of outlook
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `javax.mail` then you must set the content of the message to text/html;

```
message.setContent(body, "text/html");
```

The body of the message can then be thought of as the `<body>` tag in HTML

However, you cannot execute Javascript in an email.

Answer (score 0):

The body section is a plain text, not html markup.

Take a look at the [The mailto URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) which states the following:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
> body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
> the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is
> primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
> actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
> messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

Comment: so it is not possible to give html code as part of outlook mail body.Is there any other workaround for my requirement.If possible can you suggest me.

Comment: See [How to send an email from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript).