# Chrome Web App and Sending Email

Tags: javascript, email, google-chrome-app

I want to send an email to a user who inputs their email address in the chrome web app. How can I send the email? In chrome web apps the mailto: function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript?rq=1) You cant use javascript to send your email. However you can open the user's mail client.

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com');

window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

In chrome web apps the mailto: function does not work because I think it is not configured in the browser settings.

Try to configure it in `chrome settings->handlers, or Chrome Settings->Content Settings->Manage Handlers`

Comment: My Chrome App is a kiosk App, I can't have any new windows opening. This is where I am very confused... I just need to send a simple email from my chrome app and I have tried the things listed above and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a simple web service that your app connects to (with an XHR) and the server would send the email.