# Send Email using only Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have created a web application using angularJS and firebase. Now, I want to send E-mail to the users once they are authenticated from app. Is there any way to send email using only angular JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by integrating angularjs with email services like mandrill.
https://github.com/headcanon/mandrill-angular

Above github repository illustrates how to integrate mandrill apis with angularjs.
Hope it would help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer