# How do I send this as an email to another company that is helping me

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a demo ( not real ) piece of code below, just to give you an idea of what I want to accomplish.

```
function submitCart()
{
    var emailcontent = window.open('about:blank', 'emailcontent');
    var emailBody = emailcontent.document;
    emailBody.open();
    emailBody.write($('.home_page_container').html())
    $('.home_page_container').html()
    emailBody.close();
}
```

This code, at the moment, very nicely duplicates the Shopping Cart and opens it in a new page.  However, that isn't what I want to do. Rather than opening it as a new page, I want to send it as an email to a company that is helping me with my orders.

How do I send the html displayed by this line of code, as either an email attachment, or the body of the email?

```
$('.home_page_container').html()
```

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server side programming language.

Comment: No way to do this on the client side?

Comment: Maybe this can be usefull for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: I read that entry, actually, and was hoping that things might have changed since 2011.  :) Ok, i'll stop looking for client side solutions.

Comment: @bhardy — If you wanted to do it client side, why did you tag this [tag:ajax]? (But no, you can't do this client side).

Comment: Because, I am aware of the possibility that I may be forced to do this server side only.  I was just HOPING that there might now be simple way to send client generated shopping cart.

Comment: Use Google docs or similar collaborative document environment.

Comment: No Justin, my orders will get that lost that way.  The helping company already checks their email because that is how they receive orders from their own clients.  I want them to treat my orders just like they would an order from one of their own clients.  Its ok, I can do this server side, its just more code than I was hoping to write.

Comment: Thanks everyone for confirming what I guess I already knew, but didn't want to accept.