# Auto generated email In Oracle JET

Tags: javascript, rest, email, oracle-jet

I am creating an Oracle JET application in which I want to send an email to the user containing the user password when they click *Forgot Password*. I tried this using `mailto:` but it opens the mail client. I want the application to send mail without opening the mail client. Can someone please explain how this could be done. Can this be done only by using RESTful web services? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Arun if the answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 1):

Sending a mail requires a server-side action, i.e. connecting to an SMTP server. So if your RESTful web service is written in a language that supports SMTP, then yes you can do it. For example: http://www.journaldev.com/2532/javamail-example-send-mail-in-java-smtp

It has nothing to do it with Oracle-JET, which is just a UI framework.

**P.S.**
If you absolutely want to use client-side JavaScript just for the fun of it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21041537/4887159) shows how. But as the comments on it say, it's a complete breach of security.