# email service for send an email with nodejs in angular 4.x?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to send an email activation code for users who sign up on the website. If possible, I would like to use an Angular service so I can use it later in other projects.

Comment: It is not good to send email using angular since the email configuration will be exposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to send from client side(not using a server side like node.js, web api, wcf etc..).
You can not send directly but using external javascript libraries, apis you might able to send. Take a look here, there are pretty much discussions about sending email with javascript.

[How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

... I think you CAN NOT send an email only with Angular4 .. .but you need also a Back End implementation .. like node.js or Asp.NET or what you prefer...

example :

```
http://tphangout.com/angular-2-sending-mails-from-your-app/
```