# Best way to call a C# function in Angular to send an Email

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angular, email

I want to implement an Email Contact form on my [website](https://danielturcich.com/) ( [Source Code](https://github.com/buffet-time/DanielTurcich.com) ) where i'll prompt the user the Subject and Body line and handle sending the emails myself with a C# email client I have already written  [Here](https://github.com/buffet-time/CSharpEmailClients/tree/master/ConsoleEmailClient).

I'm wondering what is the best/ fastest/ etc. way of accomplishing implementing the C# functionality into the website. This is an Angular 4 w/ Material 2 website being hosted with Firebase.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I wouldn't want to do something needlessly resource intensive seeing as this is the only backend functionality I currently plan on implementing.

Thank you

Comment: send the subject + body of the email from the client to the backend with a post request

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge two ways, you can do this

1. Merge your both the applications into a single application and use **$.post**
2. Expose post method in the .Net application to send a mail which accepts mail details as the parameter and post the main body to function using angular script(here you need may need to handle cross-domain issues also I think).

The 2nd option looks better as long as your method exposed as web.api to receive to requests.

Comment: The first approach was to combine both the applications and make single applications and no need to worry about the cross-domain issue. Basically both the approach are same.