# How do I write script to send the reports on my mail

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am building a Django report page, and whenever user reports something, I want the message to be sent on my mail box.

How can I achieve this using either python or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can do it easily using [smtpjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48283488/9485417)

With django you can do it with `send_mail`, previously [configuring the smtp settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264907/python-django-gmail-smtp-setup)