# Vue sending email

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem. I want to put a contact form on the page, but I do not know how to do it in the Vue. I wanted to do it normally as jquery, php, but it does not work in Vue. Does anyone have an idea what I can do?

Comment: https://emailjs.org/

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue is a View (hence the name) library, meant for describing your View layer i.e. how your application looks. Such logic as sending an email would for one be dependent on Javascript itself and not on Vue.

However it is **not possible** to send an email from Javascript in the browser. Instead you'd need to build a backend which can send an email for you, or you could call the user's email client, both [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381162/3990318).

Answer (score 3):

You would ideally send email data (to, message body - html escaped of course) as a request to a backend end point and send from there. You can use Vue's HTTP resource to send the request: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

But sending an email directly from Vue isn't possible.