# how to create Html form to send email with button

Tags: html

Unable to get ths form working.

Is there any easy to create html form that will simply send email upon submission?

Can anyone provide some code samples?

I tried to get it workin but it always stay there no response on email. In form i tried to get date, time, locations that can be typed, number passanger and cars, car type, name email and message.

```
                <form class="booking-form"> 


                        <div class="row">
                        <!--    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                                <fieldset class="car-type">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="car-type" id="econo" />
                                    <label for="econo"><i class="icon-car-econo"></i>Econo</label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div> -->
```

```
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                                <fieldset class="car-type">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="car-tclass="icon-car-LUXURY SEDANype" id="LUXURY SEDAN" />
                                    <label for="LUXURY SEDAN"><i class="icon-car-classic"> </i>LUXURY SEDAN</label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                                <fieldset class="car-type">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="car-type" id="EUROPEAN SEDAN" />
                                    <label for="EUROPEAN SEDAN"><i class="icon-car-wagon"></i>EUROPEAN SEDAN</label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="text" name="from1" placeholder="From" />
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="text" name="to1" placeholder="To" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date1" class="datepicker" />
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Time" class="timepicker" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <select name="cars">
                                        <option>Cars</option>
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <select name="passengers">
                                        <option>Passengers</option>
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>

                                    </select>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <textarea name="message2" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: What server-side language are you using with this (PHP, C#, etc)? You need to set the action when the form is submitted <form action="{file to be executed, eg. Email.php}" method="POST"> and instead of just a button you need to have a submit button <input type="submit" value="Book Now" />. Need more details to help further.

Comment: its only html no server language is used.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad news my friend, but i don't see an email being sent just using Html. You'll need some kind of server-side back-end language to actually process the data from the form and the send the email. Html is only front-end.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript It's not exactly what you're looking for but the closest to sending an email.

Comment: so basically I need to learn more programming languages, I am right?

Comment: In short, yes! Good luck..

Comment: can you help me to write php file to get it working I am not able to get it working..

Answer (score 0):

you need a backend language

```
<!-- action->specify the destiny of data from form | method->indicate shipping method  -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="someText" placeholder="someText">
    <input type="submit" name="sendText" value="sendText">
</form>
```

and with php you can send the data form form

```
<?php 

    $errorMessage = ''; // case the user not complete all fields of the form
    $to = 'myemail@company.com'; // destiny of message

    if( isset($_POST['sendText']) ){ // comprobate the action of the input type submit 
        $someText = $_POST['someText']; // get the value of input type text
        if( !empty($someText) ){ // comprobate if the variable is not empty
            $someText = stripslashes(trim(filter_var($someText , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))); // this sanitize the text for avoid the code injection
            mail($to,$someText); // this method only can send message when the web is working on server
        }else{ // show an error message if text is empty
            $errorMessage.="Please complete all fields <br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: thank you i am trying to figure this code out as php is very new to me.

Comment: <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "admin@localhost"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $name . " "  "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
 $message = $email . " "  "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
 $message = $from1 . " " . $_POST['message'];
  $message = $to1 . " " "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
   $message = $date1 . " " . $_POST['message'];

Comment: $message = $cars . " " . $_POST['message'];
    $message = $passengers . " " . $_POST['message'];
 $message = $time . " " . $_POST['message'];
 $message = $date1 . " " . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
     }
?>

Comment: I like more the code with more separation between each word :), but in programming there are many ways to do something, this is the basic way to validate a <form> with php, exist other forms to make validation of forms more advanced, with the practice you will be better, if you code its works is good  :)

Comment: <form class="booking-form" form action="zero1.php" method="post">   this one redirects me to php file when i fill and submit form.

Comment: it's not actually staying on form after submitting nor to the specific page but redirecting to  PHP file link that is handling email

Comment: in the document of your form validation with php use to redirect to index for example header('Location: index.html ') to final of all code validation of form