# Is it possible to send emails only with the client-side?

Tags: javascript, email

I need to send emails in a front-end application that I'm using Vue.js, I would like to know if it's possible to send mail only with Javascript .. or do I need a server-side language for this? Thank you!

Comment: You cannot send email using front-end code. You either need to do server-side implementation or you can use services like sendgrid.com and mailgun.com, where they expose Rest APIs to do the work for you.

Comment: technically speaking, a node.js backend would still be js

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from client side [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

No you can't send an email directly with javascript. But you can open user's mail client like this:

```
window.open('mailto:abc@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Where subject and body are optional parameters.
I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but not practical. You can use smtpjs.com.
After you setup all the information, add these to your html:

HTML -> Head:

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v2/smtp.js"></script>
```

JS

```
Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
"smtp.yourisp.com",
"username",
"password");
```

If you don't want to send your credentials over http, there's also a way to encrypt it as well.

You can encrypt your SMTP credentials, and lock it to a single domain, and pass a secure token instead of the credentials instead, for example:

```
Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
{token: "63cb3a19-2684-44fa-b76f-debf422d8b00"});
```

Comment: Make sure you ask yourself "What's in it for smtpjs.com?" when you give them the keys to your mail server.

Answer (score 1):

All E-mails are sent through some kind of server so you would either need to use an API online or host a server where you could send and receive mail ([Gmail's API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) requires you to host a server).

Answer (score 1):

In theory no, you can not. However, there are options nowadays to send e-mail from the client side using third party services such as [FormCake](https://formcake.com/), [FormSpree](https://formspree.io/) and [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't send emails from javascript or Html client-side because it generates the OTP page which is must be verified then it must be a server or use any third-party API by which you can send the email.