# Implement email and sms notifications in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sms, vue-component, email

Is there any framework/component in Vue.js which enables email and phone notifications?
I couldn't find any useful topic on StackOverlow which could help me.
Any advice/solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send emails or SMS directly from your .js client. This is not a Vue.js specific - it applies to all browser clients - pure html with Javascript, Angular, React and any other. I think you should have a look at this answer:

[How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but what about the sms service? Is there any service in js which enables me to send sms notifications?

Comment: It is exactly the same as for emails. You would have to use some external service. They are called SMS Gateways and provide APIs which allow you to send SMS. I suggest you checking google for this.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you once again!