# trying to write a javascript to send my HTML form via email

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi I've wrote my CSS code and HTML but I'm struggling to get it to send in IE11, I've seen a few ways which make this possible and wondered which is best. Here is the Code I've written please help, its long but it works so far. if i told you my future depended on this would it help

```css
div {
  height: 14cm;
  width: 10cm;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

input[type=Reset] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=Reset]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>eKFI Guidance Tracker</h3>


enter code here

<div class="container">
  <form action="mailto:hard.up@pleasehelp.co.uk?subject=eKFI%20form%20submission" method="post" enctype="text/plain" <label for="MEC">MEC Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="MEC" name="MEC" placeholder="MEC Name">

    <label for="FNumber">F-Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="FNumber" name="Customer Number" placeholder="Enter customer F-Number...">

    <label for="Platform">Platform</label>
    <select id="Platform" name="Platform">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Iphone/Ipad">Iphone/Ipad</option>
      <option value="PC/Laptop">PC/Laptop</option>
      <option value="Android">Android</option>
    </select>

    <label for="Notes">Notes</label>
    <textarea id="Notes" name="Notes" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:60px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="Reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>
```

thanks in advance it would be a great help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Comment: Note: looks like your form element is missing a `>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to send emails via javascript because It is client based language. You can send It with Ajax + PHP if you don't want to "reload page" or if you can reload page only with PHP as shown on [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp).
(You have also AJAX tutorial on this page under JavaScript course).
Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I would prefer to use PHP for this action. Like @Comp says, javascript is a client based language, and is not made/used for sending mails and stuff. Ajax would be a great opportunity too. But I would prefer using PHP, which has the best results :)

Comment: You make it sound like Ajax is an alternative for PHP while the two are completely different things.

Comment: ill explain the situation a little
im trying to get one form which would be sent via email to colleagues that they can fill in and the results be sent to my inbox to monitor the query types 

will either of these work or would I have to try something new