# mailing content in a few text-boxes to a gmail with html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple project with HTML where I put my email address in one textbox and my name in another one. The problem is, I don't know how to do this. Here is my project:

https://codepen.io/dewball777/pen/KGNVyR

```
<backtext> was just an <h1> with a background and a monospace font
```

What I want is that the code should send the email to the email address in the email address textbox and the message is their name in the second textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a form with your content.

May be using js to setting mail.

Ex:

```
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"></form>
```

You can reference on : https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail

Comment: when i do this, i get this weird pop up

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot @AbhiraamEranti?

Comment: how to put a screenshot

Comment: Click edit on your question, then upload your image using the button that looks like a mountain and a sun.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mJbbpa4h_nJYLwiD7GZnSkHUdlFv3_sQexICi6p4bYk/edit

Comment: May be for this function @AbhiraamEranti

`function lol(){
  alert("this is the mailing part");
}`

Comment: @devil8910 the same thing happens for the W3 schools one

Comment: @AbhiraamEranti It is show the mail box.
Html just create a form to get information to send email. If you want to send , you need a server side(php java, ..) or try to EmailJS.

You can refer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript