# Is there any way to send user inputs as an email?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, email

As I wrote in the title, is there any way to do that?

For example, Let's say I make some form tags that users will be typing their names and email addresses and submit button with html.

And the user inputs will be sent as an email to my email address as they press the submit button.

I think it is a dangerous thing to try because of security reasons but I wanted to know if there is such a way to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: [emailJS](http://www.emailjs.com/) is your friend!

Comment: emailJS is a third party service that doesn't appear to charge you money but does want a username and password to your SMTP server and, while it encrypts those credentials so you aren't making them public, there doesn't appear to be anything to stop people using the encrypted token to relay spam through your server via emailJS. **Avoid**.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why do you think it is dangerous for security reasons ? I mean, you validate user input server side before doing anything else don't you ?

Comment: @TGrif I thought this kind of thing can be attached to the forms that user will be typing their password or personal information. I am not sure if that is 100% possible but that's what I thought. However, what I am trying to do is making a form that users can type their contact info on my website so I can contact them later on.