# How do I make my form coded in React submit to my email

Tags: reactjs

How do I make my form submit to my email? I have a form that post the comment above the textarea but I want it to post to my email as well. Thanks if you know the answer. I'll post the url in a sec.

Comment: You'll need to use either a serverside language or a 3rd party library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: Do you have any examples.

Comment: I didn't see anything in that link.

Comment: Anybody else know how to answer this.

Comment: Anyone else know the answer to this.

Comment: I''m not able to submit the url. a

Comment: I''m not able to submit the url. Anyone know of an answer.