# How to make an HTML form send data to an email address?

Tags: html, forms, input

I just started learning html and CSS and I'm in a difficult situation. I'm trying to build a website, and I'm not sure how can I get an email sent to my email address from this form. Do I need to use JavaScript in order to get the email sent? How can I do it? Can somebody help me finish this page? The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Contact Form</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you just want the Client to use their default mail program then check [this](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-mailto-links.html) out. Otherwise you need to use a Server Language like PHP, Node, Python, Java, or....You can assign the `AnchorElement.href = ` with JavaScript, if you wish to take information off of your page and put it in the email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature in HTML to send the form submission directly to an email address.

The example below is from [w3schools.com try html form mail](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail)
 where you can also see the result of the mentioned `mailto:` option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

    <form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        Name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <br> E-mail:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="mail">
        <br> Comment:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="comment" size="50">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Your code seems to come from an example like this [try hmtl form submits example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit), 
which sends query parameters as `fname=John&lname=Doe` to a php script,
which is then supposed to send the email.

Read here [how to send emails using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php), but if you just starting html and css, this is a completely different story, I hope this helps anyway. A lot of stuff to read and study.