# How to send the values of a table to an email?

Tags: html

I want to send the total value of this table to an email. I wrapped the mailto around the table but there was no success is doing that. Am I missing something here? I would like to embed this on a wix website.

```
<form action="mailto:someone@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"> <tr>
<td>Patio Set/Workshop Table/Gun Cabinet</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" value="" name="7QTY5" id="7QTY5" onKeyUp="multiply()" />
</td>
<td style=display:none;>
  <input type="text" name="7PRICE5" id="7PRICE5" value="25" readonly/>
</td>
<td style=display:none;>
  <input type="text" name="7TOTAL5" id="7TOTAL5" />
</td> <input type="button" name="Submit1" value="Calculate" onclick="javascript:add()"/><br> Total: 
<input type="text" name="9TOTAL" id="9TOTAL"  readonly/> <br>
<input type="button" name="Submit2" value="Calculate" onclick="javascript:calculate()"/><br>
<input id= "result" type= "text" value="0"/> Final Result<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: You will need a programing language to take the data collected on the HTML form and to launch this data in an email out from the server to the rest of the internet . Typically PHP is used for this as well as numerous other server side languages.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: Your HTML is completely invalid.