# How Send Data to Website Creator via a Client Event

Tags: javascript

I am creating a hopping website, and when someone creates an order and checks out, I want the following information to be sent to me, via email or some other method. There are a few pieces of data I would like to send (see below). The website is also static fyi.

I would like to send The Price they spent - a string, a list of all the items(I have an array of objects containing the data), and the shipping type - a string.

I also don't mind how the data is sent, as I'm the only one who needs this info.

Thanks!

Comment: I want the site to be able to send a message to me

Comment: "I want" still isn't a valid problem statement. What code have you written so far, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I don't really know where to start, but I have made the whole cart system, and a way to checkout. I just want a way to know what orders have come in, all in one place

Comment: e.g. send a text email with information to my email which has been specified in the code

Comment: If you truly "*don't really know where to start*", Stack Overflow isn't really the place for you. The Q&A format here is specifically to address discrete issues with code you've already written (generally speaking). It's not a good place to have your broad design decisions made for you, or to have your code written entirely when starting from nothing. This is also a duplicate of [How to send en email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript). Have you done at least any requisite research on this before posting, in accordance with [ask]?