# How can I send an email with javascript without using mailto or php?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre"/>
        <label>Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido"/>
        <label>Celular</label>
        <input type="text" name="celular"/>
        <label>Correo</label>
        <input  type="text" name="correo"/>
        <label>Mensaje</label>
        <textarea row="2" name="mensaje" ></textarea>
        <button type="button" onclick="">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript || https://www.emailjs.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Comment: No, I want it to be done without mailto or php.

Comment: Think you can't with JS is a client-side language, mail is a server-side action.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Simple-Mailer](https://parkingmaster.github.io/Simple-Mailer) has it's own repository now and has different functions and APIs now ([simplemailer.loca.lt](https://simplemailer.loca.lt))

Free signup, unlimited emails and custom functions.

Just sign up, get your API key and embed it like this:

```html
<script src="https://simplemailer.loca.lt/js/YOUR_API_KEY/mailer.js"></script>
```

Here's a new working example:

```js
  let isSent = false;
  function send() {
    if (!isSent) {
      const value = document.querySelector("[name=email]").value;
      email(value, "My name", "This is a test subject", "You can put plaintext or <b>HTML</b> here").then(function() {
        isSent = true;
        alert("Sent to: " + value);
      }).catch(err => alert(err));
    } else {
      alert("Spam alert!");
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://simplemailer.loca.lt/js/S7w12OjlEOz6WprNHiO3KvwGhfLJ7OZP9e4Klh3d63cV6EldSlYtAATAzRhe6Upl2/mailer.js"></script>

<input type="email" name="email" value="test@example.com" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="send()" />
```

It's much better than [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com), because you can make your own custom function name, it's much simpler and it's completely free!