# How do i use javascript to send an email, like google classroom does

Tags: javascript, email

I am trying to make a simple feedback button to automatically open email and have it being sent to my email. but i am not sure how.

I have tried geeksforgeeks but it doesnt really work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript) answer your question?

Comment: @HoangSon 
no it does not. it will not work at all..