# Email Using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create webpage where user can entered its detail like first name, last name, address and phone number. Once they have entered details and click on Send button it should send email to my email address and it should redirect to another page.

I am able to send email using mailto:email@gmail.com but it opens outlook with user details and then they need to click on send button to send email. I don't want outlook to be open and it should directly send email when they click on send button on form.

I am using JavaScript for validation and basic HTML tag to create form. Can anyone help me how to send email directly using HTML/JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending emails with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to send an email with just JavaScript and HTML, you'll need some server side code to use a mailing protocol to send it out automatically. If you have web server setup you can then a server side language like PHP to create a script to send the data, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to send an email using client side code.

You need to submit the data to a server and process it with a server side program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an email directly from client-side HTML/JS. You need to do it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said, you can't send email from the client side. However, you can use JavaScript to call a server-side script using an XMLHttpRequest, or jsonp if you're restricted by the same origin policy.

If you're new to serverside scripting, I'd suggest checking out PHP and its [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.