# Email content in html format

Tags: javascript, html, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

I want to send email from javascript. I found this post which helped me alot [Sending emails with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript).

But I need to add image, bold text and color changes in email content.

Any help?

**What i tried:**

```
var content = "I want to send email from javascript. <span style='color:red'>I found this post which helped me alot</span><img src='logo.png'/> Sending emails with Javascript"

var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
         + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
         + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
         + "&body=" + escape(content);

window.location.href = link;
```

Comment: Show you html code you want to send in a mail

Comment: That's not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body

Comment: What application handles the mailto will depend entirely on the user's configuration, so there isn't a one size fit all querystring you can use.

Comment: What application handles the mailto will depend entirely on the user's configuration, so there isn't a one size fit all querystring you can use.

Comment: I don't think it's possible . as far as I know

Comment: @Tornado. when i copy and paste some HTML contents thunderbird and outlook renders them correctly. Why can't i from javasctipt?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible . as far as I know , you can just pass \n for new line

```
"mailto:me@me.com?body=xx " + escape("\n") + " xx"
```

why not let user write the conent in email client?