# HTTP5, Jquery client side email sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Main target is to implement instant annonymous e-mail sending from web by client side script. Don't know if it`s event possible, but maybe you know some workarounds, or maybe some e-mail providers allow to send annonymous e-mails by posting data or have some API for that..

Found [how to send mail to gmail by javascript](http://blog.jrmoran.com/sending-an-email-message-to-gmail-with-javasc/), but problem is you need to have gmail account..

Thanks!

Comment: Spammers would love this! I heard there is a guy that wants to give me a billion dollars.

Comment: Of course it's possible - if you set up your own mail server for example. But you'd just invite huge amounts of spam so I doubt anyone has been silly enough to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript

Answer (score -1):

You could have a server-side script set up to watch for HTTP requests that contain a special key or API that would send an email based on hard-coded parameters, or parameters the request contain. On the client-side, you would just set up an AJAX request to call this server-side script. You could use Perl, PHP, Python, etc. to accomplish this.