# how to send email from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how to send email using javascript/HTML5 .
I created a from inside html with the parameters (Email To, Email Subject, Email Body)
and i want to know how to send an email 
Thanks

Comment: What email address would you expect it to be sent _from_?

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/send-email-with-javascript

Comment: You can't do that client side. You can only send an e-mail using server script.

Comment: are you trying to send mail without opening the local mail client? say Outlook? Already a couple of links posted, but I think this might be useful too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268796/how-do-i-send-email-with-javascript-without-opening-the-mail-client

Comment: this link can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript

Comment: yes i dont want to open outlook to send an email

Comment: There seems to be a new solution at the horizon. It's called [EmailJS](http://www.emailjs.com). They claim that no server code is needed. You can request an invitation.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it with pure html/javascript.
If you don't use ant 3-rd party service for email sending, where you can sent your data and it will do rest (i.e. [Mailgun](http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html)), then you'll need support from server side to accomplish this (php, asp.net, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

refer this link http://www.javatpoint.com/java-mail-api-tutorial this will show how to do send emails using smtp .but we cannot send mails by using only javascript and html