# Submitting outputs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, email, submit, output, document.write

I am trying to send the values visualized in a new window (through the function "salva()") to my email address, but I do not have any knowledge of php, thus I would like to do it using only js...how can I do?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Esercizio vettori</title>

    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
        <h1>Esercizio</h1>

        <input id="punti1" type="button" value="1" />
        <input id="punti2" type="button" value="2" />

        <input id="testo" type="text" placeholder="Commento utente" />
        <input id="mostra" type="button" value="Salva e mostra" onclick="inserisci();salva()" />

      </form>

      <div id="visualizza">Qui visualizzerà i risultati</div>

    <script>


    var punteggio = [];
    var orario = [];
    var testo = [];
    var inputPunti = [];

    document.getElementById("punti1").onclick = function() {

    inputPunti = document.getElementById("punti1"); 
    inserisci ();

    }; 

    document.getElementById("punti2").onclick = function() {

    inputPunti = document.getElementById("punti2");
    inserisci ();

    }; 





var inputTesto = document.getElementById("testo");
var risultato  = document.getElementById("visualizza");

function inserisci () {

 punteggio.push( inputPunti.value );
 orario.push( Date() );
 testo.push( inputTesto.value );

 pulisci();
}

function pulisci () {
  // Pulisce i campi
  //* inputPunti.value = "";
  orario.value = Date();
  inputTesto.value = "";


}


function salva()
  {
 var doc=window.open();
window.open();
 doc.document.write(punteggio);
 doc.document.write(orario);
 doc.document.write(testo); 
  }


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a backend to properly sanitize user input, the easiest and safest way to achieve this is to follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript). To achieve what I think you want, you should explore putting an email library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) on your server (assuming you are using PHP). You can easily find a lot of resources on how to use them online.