# populating an email "to, cc" and body using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

Everything seems to work fine except when i try to populate `to` box...

my code:

```
Email: <input type="text" id="myTex">

<textarea id="myText">
   lorsem ipsum
</textarea>
<button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>

<script>
function sendMail() {
    var link = "&mailto=" + escape(document.getElementById('myTex').value)
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Welcome New agent! ")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}</script>
```

I have a problem with my Email input, it's breaking everything.. perhaps my syntax is wrong? I've tried a few different things but to no avail.. Hopefully it's something simple and i just need another set of eyes. As usual.. any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending emails with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript)

Comment: That's actually where i got the code from and I've left a new comment over there but no one has responded. Thanks Joe. =]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change

```
var link = "&to="
```

to

```
var link = "mailto:"
```

Comment: `var link =  "mailto:" + escape(document.getElementById('myTex').value)`  is not working either..

Comment: To debug this, ignore the javascript and just make the url yourself.  You should be able to put a "mailto:" link manually in your browser's address bar and have it work.  If it doesn't, then it is probably a problem with your mail client.

Comment: In your browser's address bar, type "mailto:a@a.com" and press enter.  If that doesn't work, the problem is with your mail client, not your javascript.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm not following you.. outlook opens for me fine and populates all the fields accordingly except the `to` field.

Comment: So if you go to "mailto:a@a.com", you see a new email window in Outlook, but there isn't anything in the "To" field?  If that's correct, then try it on another computer.  The problem is somewhere else.