# Open New Email in Default Application with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, email, owncloud

I appreciate any and all help on this.  I am a novice.
I am customizing an OwnCloud setup, which has a great setup for sharing a link that the application creates via an internal system, but I need it to open an email in the default email application (such as Outlook) and have the link in the email.  I am hoping to customize the code that is already there.  There is a share.js file and a share.php file.  Here are the excerpts from the share.js:

Option 1 -  The form area that action contains the link that I'd like to include in the email:

```
        html += '<label for="linkText" class="hidden-visually">'+t('core', 'Link')+'</label>';
        html += '<input id="linkText" type="text" readonly="readonly" />';
        html += '<input type="checkbox" name="showPassword" id="showPassword" value="1" style="display:none;" /><label for="showPassword" style="display:none;">'+t('core', 'Password protect')+'</label>';
        html += '<div id="linkPass">';
        html += '<label for="linkPassText" class="hidden-visually">'+t('core', 'Password')+'</label>';
        html += '<input id="linkPassText" type="password" placeholder="'+t('core', 'Choose a password for the public link')+'" />';
        html += '<span class="icon-loading-small hidden"></span>';
        html += '</div>';
```

I tried changing it several ways, such as:

```
        html += '<form method="POST" action="mailto:kyle.s@pandplandservice.com?body=Link">';
        html += '<label for="linkText" class="hidden-visually">'+t('core', 'Link')+'</label>';
        html += '<input id="linkText" type="text" readonly="readonly" />';
        html += '<input type="checkbox" name="showPassword" id="showPassword" value="1" style="display:none;" /><label for="showPassword" style="display:none;">'+t('core', 'Password protect')+'</label>';
        html += '<div id="linkPass">';
        html += '<label for="linkPassText" class="hidden-visually">'+t('core', 'Password')+'</label>';
        html += '<input id="linkPassText" type="password" placeholder="'+t('core', 'Choose a password for the public link')+'" />';
        html += '<span class="icon-loading-small hidden"></span>';
        html += '<br />';
        html += '<input type="submit" value="Send Link" />';
        html += '</form>';
        html += '</div>';
```

And then I do get an email to open up, but it does not contain the link.

Option 2  -  This is the part of the form that sends a message from the application, but I need it to open up an email message that contains the same stuff it would send internally (or at the very least the link):

```
                            html += '<form id="emailPrivateLink">';
            html += '<input id="email" style="display:none; width:62%;" value="" placeholder="'+t('core', 'Email link to person')+'" type="text" />';
            html += '<input id="emailButton" style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Send Email" />';
```

And the part of the js file that that form references:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#dropdown #emailPrivateLink', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $('#linkText').val();
    var itemType = $('#dropdown').data('item-type');
    var itemSource = $('#dropdown').data('item-source');
    var file = $('tr').filterAttr('data-id', String(itemSource)).data('file');
    var email = $('email').val();
    var expirationDate = '';
    if ( $('#expirationCheckbox').is(':checked') === true ) {
        expirationDate = $( "#expirationDate" ).val();
    }
    if (email !='') {
        $('#email').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#email').val(t('core', 'Sending ...'));
        $('#emailButton').prop('disabled', true);
        $.post(OC.filePath('core', 'ajax', 'share.php'), { action: 'email', toaddress: email, link: link, itemType: itemType, itemSource: itemSource, file: file, expiration: expirationDate},
            function(result) {
                $('#email').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#emailButton').prop('disabled', false);
            if (result && result.status == 'success') {
                $('#email').css('font-weight', 'bold');
                $('#email').animate({ fontWeight: 'normal' }, 2000, function() {
                    $(this).val('');
                }).val(t('core','Email Sent'));
            } else {
                OC.dialogs.alert(result.data.message, t('core', 'Error while sharing'));
```

Any and all help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + escape("This is content of email")
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
```

[Sending emails with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript)

Comment: I cannot get this to format right.
Okay, I'm going to show how little i know here... I tried:

<pre><code>
html += '<span class="icon-loading-small hidden"></span>';
html += '<button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>';
function sendMail() {
var link = "mailto:"
+ "&subject=" + escape("I would like to share a file with you from The P&P Cloud")
  + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementByID('#linkText').value)
;
window.location.href = link;
}
html += '</div>';
</code></pre>

But this just reloads the page with "?showPassword=1" on the end of the URL. What did I not place correctly?

Comment: @user1754510 Your code is not clear. `function sendMail() { 
 var link = "mailto:" + "&subject=" + escape("I would like to share a file with you from The P&P Cloud") + 
 "&body=" + escape(document.getElementByID('#linkText').value) ; 
 window.location.href = link; 
} 
var html += '<div><span class="icon-loading-small hidden"></span>'; 
html += '<button onclick="sendMail(); return false;">Send</button>'; 
html += '</div>'; `