# Possibility to Receive and Send Emails with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, database, webserver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJimt.jpg)I wrote a static website at pages.github.io. Since I did not have a server, I couldn’t realise data interaction, for example as with regard to users’ messages. Therefore, I was wondering if it were possible to use JavaScript to send users’ data through email and receive the other users’ emails, as a way to achieve data interaction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending emails with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mailgun APIs that enable you to send,
receive and track email effortlessly. https://smtpjs.com/

```
Email.send("from@you.com","to@them.com","This is a subject","this is the body","smtp.yourisp.com","username","password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Sending emails with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript). Personally, I'd prefer some service to this solution, though. Checkout Formspree: https://formspree.io/ It seems to be made for this kind of thing and does not require any JavaScript.

If you need more control, https://aws.amazon.com/ses is Amazon's simple email service. Where you could send your message via an API. Mailgun (https://www.mailgun.com/) is similar and probably cheaper to add to your page.