# Is there a way to change From address in outlook via javascript?

Tags: javascript, outlook

I want to change the "From" email address in outlook via javascript. I am able to set values for Subject,To,Cc. 
Please suggest me to achieve this if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [SMTP service](https://www.smtpjs.com/) to change From address.

For example:

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v2/smtp.js"> </script>

Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject", 
 "this is the body", 
 "smtp.yourisp.com", 
 "username", 
 "password");
```

Reference from:

[Sending emails with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript)