# function and getElementById not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, send

I have created a page where if the input length is 0, it shows an alert. And if input length is not 0, it does the function that `href"mailto:info@company.com"` property does(Did it with `document.getElementByID`). I want that after clicking on Send button, it sends an email or does the function that Html's `href"mailto:info@company.com"` property does. But it is not working. The code is:

HTML:

```
<form action="index.html">
   <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send" onClick="auth(event)">
   <div>
     <a href="mailto:info@company.com" id="SendMail"></a>
   </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function auth(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

  if (username.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter your email");
    return;
  } else if (username.length === 5) {
    document.getElementById("SendMail")
  } 
  }
```

Comment: What do you expect `document.getElementById("SendMail")` to do? It just references an element and does nothing.

Comment: You are trying to `getElementById(“username”)` which isn’t in the html. You need to add an element with that ID. Also you have `onClick` vice `onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just taking the ID reference and doing nothing with it. I think what you want to do is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/271172/2938055