# Sending email in Javascript

Tags: javascript

According to [Sending emails with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript), one way to do it is the following:

```
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + encodeURIComponent("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myText').value)
    ;
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

However I'm trying to personalize it, sending emails with variables. I did this:

```
function sendMail(subject="test", body, mail="test@gmail.com") {
  var link = `mailto:${mail}`
           + "&subject=" + encodeURIComponent(`${subject}`)
           + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(`${body}`)
  ;
  window.location.href = link;
```

But, when sending the email, I achieve this
fail:

[image: fail (image)]

It seems like it is not recognizing each variable. How to solve it?

Comment: You're missing the `?`, which separates the URL from the query string. Also, a better way to construct a full URL with query string is to use the `new URL()` object

Comment: Note that you can't rely on your visitor having a mail client installed and working that `mailto:` can use. I don't have one and `mailto:` links just don't work for me. If you want to be able to send email from a form pass the message to your server and have that send the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string should be start with ? not &

change &subject to ?subject

it should be //abc@example.com?subject=blahblahblah&body=testtest

Answer (score 1):

The link have to be like that :

```js
var link = `mailto:${mail}`
           + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(`${subject}`)
           + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(`${body}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code for sending email. I am sure it will work..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail() {
            Email.send({
                Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
                Username : "<sender’s email address>",
                Password : "<email password>",
                To : '<recipient’s email address>',
                From : "<sender’s email address>",
                Subject : "<email subject>",
                Body : "<email body>",
            })
            .then(function(message){
                alert("mail sent successfully")
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form method="post">
        <input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendEmail()"/>
    </form>  
</body>
```

And just remember if you are using JavaScript in any other file then just link it will your HTML file! And this is the not fully coded by me I have done some research from internet.