# Is it possible to send email with only jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can I send email using jQuery only? I don't have .Net or PHP etc running on the site.

Comment: Do you have another site that could send email for you?

Comment: Releted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592/can-i-use-javascript-to-create-a-client-side-email

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not send email with Jquery. You will have to use sever-side language such as `php`, `asp.net` etc. Since you don't have these already installed, you will have to install them to be able to actually send emails. Also, even if you have these installed, you will still need an email sending mechanism, for example email settings at your host where you upload your site.

Comment: Well, if you run e-mail server on port 80 technically you can :)

Comment: @HeavyWave: Yeah, that is possible though :)